# Rails confirmation email aol parsing error with email name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parsing, email, mailto, aol

When I get a confirmation email sent via my rails app, I use this code

```
<a href='mailto:John%20Doe<Johndoe@random.com>?subject=Billing%20Submission'>LINK</a>
```

The email that shows up in all different emails is good except for aol.

In aol, it shows up as:
?subject=Billing%20Submission'>LINK

Is there any way around this without compromising the name being added?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
<a href='mailto:John%20Doe<Johndoe@random.com>?subject=Billing%20Submission'>LINK</a>
```

With

```
<a href='mailto:John%20Doe%3CJohndoe@random.com%3E?subject=Billing%20Submission'>LINK</a>
```

`>` after `Johndoe@random.com` was actually ending the starting tag of `a` (anchor).

Use *URL encoding equivalent* for `< (%3C)` and `> (%3E)` sign.

Comment: I had tried this and tried it again just now, still doesn't work.

Comment: I just tried it in my application and it works perfectly and even opens the default mail application upon clicking. Are you sure you copied the code exactly `<a href='mailto:John%20Doe%3CJohndoe@random.com%3E?subject=Billing%20Submission'>LINK</a>`

Comment: Just had to clear my cache, but it works!
Thanks a lot!